# Bash script magento

Tags: magento2, script

I created a simple bash script to automate some activities in magento administration.
The options that are contained in the script are commands that I execute frequently.

Leave your comment if you have any questions or suggestions for improvement.

[Link to script](https://pastebin.com/i9kUwyjc)

[image: Bash script magento]

Comment: The script is perfect. I have a quite similar script for myself. I would suggest adding Magento path dynamically.
Currently, I take the current working directory as Magento root, so with only one script, I am able to handle my all local Magento versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun & https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2 for mage 1 & 2 respectively.
Is there something else that you are trying to achieve here, that these tools don't already provide?